# bundle product import in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have installed magento 1.7.2 version, now my requirement is to import Bundle products but by default magento won't provide these feature.

So can anyone know that how can I import the bundle product from CSV file or if have any alternative solution then please advise.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

CSV Files contains:

### Fields:

sku , _store , _attribute_set, _type, _category , _root_category , _product_websites ,  description , enable_googlecheckout , has_options , image , image_label , msrp_enabled  name , bundle_options , bundle_selections , price , required_options , short_description , small_image , small_image_label , special_from_date , special_price , special_to_date ,  status , tax_class_id , thumbnail , thumbnail_label , updated_at , url_key , url_path

### Values:

bb2 , Default , bundle , Furniture , Default , Category , base , This is 2 bundle product , 1 , 1 ,     no_selection , No , BB , RAM,radio,1,0 , ram:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:0 , 1 , Bundle Test Product 2 , no_selection , 01-10-13 0:00 , 30-10-13 0:00 , 1 , no_selection , 07-10-13 14:38 , bb2 , bb.html

Comment: you would have to create products one by one. Read the Magento's API on how to add products and categories pragmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the Magento Dataflow (System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow - Advanced Profiles). Create a new profile, and add in the following for your Profile Actions XML:

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[name_of_file.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productimport</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

Next you'll want to create a CSV file with the following fields: `store, websites, attribute, type, sku, name, price, bundle_options, bundle_selections` and any other fields you want to upload.

Now comes the tricky part: filling in those fields. The bundle options are in the following format:  `product1_name,selection_type,default_qty,position|product2_name,selection_type,default_qty,position`.  So it will look like `product1,radio,1,0|product2,radio,1,0`

Bundle_selections is a bit tougher, but looks like this:

`product1_sku:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:0|product2_sku:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:`

**Edit:**

Example CSV File

> store,websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,name,price,short_description,description,value_offer,image,small_image,thumbnail,guarantee,weight,tax_class_id,po_box,status,visibility,grouped,bundle_options,bundle_selections,price_type,sku_type
>   admin,"base",Default,bundle,7,product_sku,My Product Name,,"Really long description here","Another description bit here","value offer here",/image.png,/image.png,/image.png,"more text",19,None,no,Enabled,"Catalog, Search",,"Name1,radio,1,0|Name2,radio,1,0",Sku1:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:0|Sku2:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:,0,1

Comment: I don't have a sample CSV file, just my own file with company information. Sorry. But I can show you an example. I'll update the answer with it.

Comment: That's pretty much it. You can try creating a bundle product and exporting it to see the exact fields and format.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the bundle_options, and the rest of the columns don't match up.

Comment: I have just change the  <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productimport</var> to  <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_product</var> and it resolve the above error and import the product. But the bundle items is not appearing on both backend and frontend.

Comment: Sorry, beyond this, I really can't help. I'd have to sit down and debug the actual program and CSV to figure out the issue.

Comment: Can you tell me the details of bundle selection field. I mean the product1_sku:0:0.0000:1:1.0000:0 what it is represented.

Comment: Digging into the code in app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Productimport.php, I think it's `sku:price_type:price_value:is_default:selection_qty:user_can_change_qty`

Comment: Now that I look into the code, it's actually product_import from CommerceThemes. This was installed by the company that originally set up our store, and considering the location, I didn't notice it wasn't a built-in function.

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears to be a paid extension

Comment: If the posted answer does not work without proprietary code, it's probably a good idea to note that on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MAGMI? It supports bundles from recent time.

It is easy to import bundles with it. You can check official documentation in wiki.magmi.org

For example, the simplest syntax for importing bundle products:

```
 ....,bundle_skus,....
 ....,"CPU:sku001;CPU:sku002",....
```

And the advanced one

```
 ....,store,bundle_options,bundle_skus,....
 ....,en,"-*;CPU:Central Processing Unit:radio:1:0;RAM:Random Access Memory:SKU:1:1","CPU:sku001:1:0:1:0;CPU:sku002:1:0:0:1;RAM:sku1000;RAM:sku1001;RAM:sku1002",....
```

If you consider paid extensions there is a nice extension [here](http://www.magelynx.com/import-export-plugin.html), it's an ui wrap around MAGMI that also supports exporting product data in magmi format, not only import as plain magmi. It works with Google spreadsheets instead of CSV and exports data right into the csv columns with headers according to magmi syntax.